# Using Keras with HDF5Matrix with labels only

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, hdf5, h5py

I believe that this is my first question in Stack Overflow, so I apologize in advance if I don't follow all guidelines.
I recently started to use Keras for deep learning, and since I work with HDF5 files using h5py to manage large datasets, I searched for a way to train models using keras on very large HDF5 files. I found out that the most common way would be to use HDF5Matrix found in [keras.utils.io_utils](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/io_utils.py).

I modified one of Keras examples ([mnist.cnn](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py)) as following:

```
'''Trains a simple convnet on the MNIST dataset.

Gets to 99.25% test accuracy after 12 epochs
(there is still a lot of margin for parameter tuning).
16 seconds per epoch on a GRID K520 GPU.
'''

from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

# My Imports
from os.path import exists
import h5py
from keras.utils.io_utils import HDF5Matrix
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

# convert class vectors to binary class matrices
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

#-----------------------------------HDF5 files creation---------------------------------------
sample_file_name = "x.hdf5"
solution_file_name = "y.hdf5"
train_name = "train"
test_name = "test"

#Create dataset
if (not exists(sample_file_name)) and (not exists(solution_file_name)):
    samples_file = h5py.File(sample_file_name,mode='a')
    solutions_file = h5py.File(solution_file_name,mode='a')
    samples_train = samples_file.create_dataset(train_name,data=x_train)
    samples_test = samples_file.create_dataset(test_name, data=x_test)
    solution_train = solutions_file.create_dataset(train_name, data=y_train)
    solution_test = solutions_file.create_dataset(test_name, data=y_test)
    samples_file.flush()
    samples_file.close()
    solutions_file.flush()
    solutions_file.close()

x_train = HDF5Matrix(sample_file_name,train_name)
x_test = HDF5Matrix(sample_file_name,test_name)
y_train = HDF5Matrix(solution_file_name,train_name)
y_test = HDF5Matrix(solution_file_name,test_name)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# If using HDF5Matrix one needs to disable shuffle
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          shuffle=False)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

However, there is something that concerns me. In segmentation problems \ multi-class problems, where the number of classes is very large, saving the solutions in categorical format is very wasteful. Moreover, doing that means that once you add a new class, the entire dataset should be changed accordingly.
That's why I thought using the normalizer feature of HDF5Matrix as following:

```
'''Trains a simple convnet on the MNIST dataset.

Gets to 99.25% test accuracy after 12 epochs
(there is still a lot of margin for parameter tuning).
16 seconds per epoch on a GRID K520 GPU.
'''

from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import backend as K

# My Imports
from os.path import exists
import h5py
from keras.utils.io_utils import HDF5Matrix
batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12

# input image dimensions
img_rows, img_cols = 28, 28

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

#-----------------------------------HDF5 files creation---------------------------------------
sample_file_name = "x.hdf5"
solution_file_name = "y.hdf5"
train_name = "train"
test_name = "test"

#Create dataset
if (not exists(sample_file_name)) and (not exists(solution_file_name)):
    samples_file = h5py.File(sample_file_name,mode='a')
    solutions_file = h5py.File(solution_file_name,mode='a')
    samples_train = samples_file.create_dataset(train_name,data=x_train)
    samples_test = samples_file.create_dataset(test_name, data=x_test)
    solution_train = solutions_file.create_dataset(train_name, data=y_train)
    solution_test = solutions_file.create_dataset(test_name, data=y_test)
    samples_file.flush()
    samples_file.close()
    solutions_file.flush()
    solutions_file.close()

x_train = HDF5Matrix(sample_file_name,train_name)
x_test = HDF5Matrix(sample_file_name,test_name)
y_train = HDF5Matrix(solution_file_name,train_name,normalizer=lambda solution: keras.utils.to_categorical(solution,num_classes))
y_test = HDF5Matrix(solution_file_name,test_name,normalizer=lambda solution: keras.utils.to_categorical(solution,num_classes))
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# If using HDF5Matrix one needs to disable shuffle
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          shuffle=False)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

However, this yields an error implying that the shape of the solution should match, and normalizer shouldn't be used that way:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2, but got array with shape (60000, 1, 10)
```

So, is there a way to save the data in HDF5 (and if not possible, using some other format), and use Keras in a manner that saves the labels (and not the categorical vector) without turning it into a regression problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because of [these](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/8a0e97abb3c6833655e480df040f52d3424e576d/keras/engine/training.py#L123) lines.

Keras checks input shapes before training. The problem is that *HDF5Matrix* will return the pre-normalized shape if you call `.shape`, then Keras will believe you have a *(60000,)* array for `y_train` and a (10000,) for `y_test`.

However, when accessing a slice of the matrix, the normalizer is applied so that for example `y_train[5:7].shape` does have the final expected shape: *(2, 10)*.

This is mainly because the normalizer isn't really expected to change the shape, but Keras could indeed handle this case.

You can fix it by using `fit_generator` instead of `fit` so that training only sees normalized data:

```
def generator(features, labels, size):
    while True:
        start, end = 0, size
        while end < len(features):
            s = slice(start, end)
            # you can actually do the normalization here if you want
            yield features[s], labels[s]
            start, end = end, end + size

model.fit_generator(
    generator(x_train, y_train, batch_size),
    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // batch_size,
    epochs=1,
    verbose=1, 
    validation_data=generator(x_test, y_test, batch_size),
    validation_steps=len(x_test) // batch_size,
    shuffle=False)
```

Note that you could do any kind of normalization inside the generator function and that will be transparent to Keras. And you can use different batch sizes for train and validation.

Also, you have to change the evaluation in the same way:

```
score = model.evaluate_generator(
    generator(x_test, y_test, batch_size),
    steps=len(x_test) // batch_size)
```

I think your solution with the normalizer is a good idea, by the way.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question so quickly. Unfortunately I have a small issue with this solution. I'm working with a very large dataset, and I plan to migrate a large part of my code to solve a segmentation problem. The y dataset would be images, hence, taking a lot of memory. Wouldn't the solution you suggested cause the entire y dataset to load into memory (potentially creating overflow)?

Comment: @DolevShapira indeed I was afraid that could be the case. I've edited my solution to use a generator so that you don't have this problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help! I thought I might be able to evade the fit_generator because of the complexity it introduces through HDF5Matrix alone. Apparantly, it was inevitable after all.

Comment: Good luck! And please mark the solution as correct if you agree that's the case.